# Is it possible to check an MP3 for data corruption?

Tags: mp3, music, libraries, file-corruption

I was listening to some older mp3s today and I released that some of my songs have pops and cracks in them.  I assume this means that the file has some bad blocks.

Is there software/script/etc that I can run on my entire library and find the music with these artifacts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the [File Integrity Verifier](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_verifier) plugin can check your library for broken files for all types of audio it supports.

And as Mark Johnson said, if the pops and clicks are in files that otherwise check out ok, then either your rip was bad or it's really part of the song.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Checkmate](http://checkmate.gissen.nl/) mp3 checker, which has multi-platform `mpck(1)` cli and Windows additionally has graphical UI. Code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sjord/checkmate)