# Can't edit MP3 tags like artist or title

Tags: windows, mp3, metadata, tags

I try to edit the tags of MP3 files and I found that some of the file cannot be edited.

Here's the procedure when I edit the information of the MP3 file:

1. Right click the MP3 file in Windows Explorer and click Properties.
2. Switch to "Details" tab and then edit the MP3 information, such as Title, Artist and Composer.

This is the message that I get if I try to save it:

> "An unexpected error is keeping you from applying properties to the file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x8007000D: The data is invalid.

May I know why this happens and whether there is any solution for the same?

Comment: Those files are most likely corrupted in some way. See [Is it possible to check an MP3 for data corruption?](http://superuser.com/questions/137998/is-it-possible-to-check-an-mp3-for-data-corruption)

Comment: Check this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/add-edit-media-player-media-information#1TC=windows-7

Comment: May be that headers are corrupt. I had the same problem and fixed it with mp3val.

Answer (score 16):

There's two options I'd look at seriously. Firstly, if you're convinced there's major issues with the tag, [mp3diags might do a good job fixing it](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/). Naturally read the big red and yellow print, and keep backups before using a program that makes substantial changes to your files.

The other would be to use a dedicated tag editor - I use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) a lot to do your tag editing, assuming its just windows being silly. I'd use this anyway to manage files since its a lot simpler than using explorer for large numbers of files.

Comment: mp3tag was able to change it without any warnings, thanks

Comment: Windows doesn't let me edit the file as if it's read-only. mp3diags `Remove non-basic ID3V2 frames` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, not being able to edit my MP3 detail.

I used MP3tag to resolve the issue (if you don't have it, then use this link [MP3tag Free Download](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) to download and install - it's free and bug free)

1. Open the MP3 with MP3tag
2. Right clicked on the MP3 (a pop-up menu will appear)
3. Select "Remove Tag" to remove the tag
4. Save

Now you can edit your MP3 with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and found its due to Windows inability to read ID3 V2.4 meta tags. The simplest method I have found to fix (that doesn't involve re-encoding) is to use tag editing software such as ID3-TagIT 3 to change them back to v2.3.

The method to do this using this software is to open the album folder in the software and select all the files.
From the top menu's select Extended Functions > Transfer/Convert Tags
In the menu that appears click Convert TAG Ver. 2.4 to Ver 2.3 (Ensure all check boxes are ticked EXCEPT Do not overwrite existing TAG entries) which can remain unticked...

Having gone round in circles on thinking it was "read only" properties on the folder permissions discovering this has been very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick fix:

1. Rename the file to something shorter
2. Right click and click *properties*
3. Uncheck the *Read only* box at the bottom
4. Click *Apply*
5. Remove and re-add to iTunes, now you can now edit all the files information

Comment: This was it - "Read only" was checked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided:

After some research I found other users experiencing the same problem:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/fd434d22-8765-44db-8b17-2257a3619255

I don't know your exact circumstances but the general problem seems to lie in the metafile.

The general solution seems to be either open up the mp3 file in some sort of sound editor (for example... Audicity).  Then resave (Save As ---> mp3).

OR

Convert all your files to .wav then back to mp3.

Comment: Alternatively, freeware is available to help change the file details. If you searched Google with your error code you will find plenty of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems applying values to properties in Properties dialog.  In file manager, some or all of the values such as Artist, album etc were blank and could not be edited.  This was caused by decompressing RAR archives with long file names which seems to corrupt the files in some way.  My solution was re-name RAR archive to short name and re-decompress.

Answer (score 0):

You could have ID3v2.4 tag in that file.

There is **no v2.4 support** in Windows Media Player 10 and older.

Tags in Windows are handled by library installed with Windows Media Player)

There are few solutions:

- update your Windows Media Player 11 (if possible)

or

- find some application that handles ID3 v2.4

or

- remove ID3v2 tag (in Winamp or AIMP or any other app)