# Why can't I edit audio file proprieties?

Tags: audio, mp3, tags, properties

So I just downloaded a song and it works just fine, the pc can open and play it. But it doesn't let me edit the details like "Artist" or "Album" and it's blank. And if I use and tag editor it has errors even opening it. What can I do?

Even I after unblock it it still won't work.

[image: What it shows me when I try to change the proprieties]

Answer (score 0):

A file downloaded from the internet needs to be unblocked.

Right-click the file in Explorer, set it to unblocked and click OK.

If this does not help, Windows cannot update this metadata, and
you will need to use a third-party product.

See this post for suggestions:
[Can't edit MP3 tags like artist or title](https://superuser.com/questions/604583/cant-edit-mp3-tags-like-artist-or-title).

Comment: I did and it still won't let me

Comment: Do you have a link to this file?

Comment: Yes. https://ytmp3.cc/en41/ and put this link in it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ENpRYyoQ1M&ab_channel=MetroBoomin (or any music video and convert it to mp3)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. Click on "Contributing artist". The entire line will highlight blue. Now click in the right hand side of the blue band and this section of the ban will go white while leaving "Contrubiting artist" blue. You can now click into the white bit an type in the name of the artist